# Gilbert Strang, Introduction to Linear Algebra 5th Edition, Problem 34, Problem Set 2.1

Tags: linear-algebra

I took this problem from the book Introduction to Linear Algebra 5th Edition (Gilbert Strang).

Problem 34, Page 45, Problem Set 2.1.

---

Start from the four equations $-x_{i+1}+2x_i-x_{i-1}=i$ (for $i=1,2,3,4$ with $x_0=x_5=0$). Write those equations in their matrix form $Ax=b$. Can you solve them for $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$?

---

$\begin{bmatrix}
2 &-1 &0 &0 \\
-1 &2 &-1 &0 \\
0 &-1 &2 &-1 \\
0 &0 &-1 &2
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2\\
x_3\\
x_4
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
2\\
3\\
4
\end{bmatrix}$

---

I just don't know what Gilbert wants us to do here because at this stage, the book hasn't mentioned the way to Eliminating and just introduced to linear equations, the column/row picture...

Comment: You could take equations $2,3,4$, pass the terms with $x_4$ to the other side and solve for $x_1,x_2,x_3$, just like system (6) on page 23 was solved. Put these values in equation $1$ and you get an equation with $x_4$ alone.

Comment: Notice the symmetry of the matrix. What do you think that says?

Comment: @conditionalMethod Sorry but I can't find the system (6) on page 23 as you said @@. Would you mind checking its link again, please? @@

Comment: Maybe they changed it from edition 4th to edition 5th. It is just a triangular system. The same this one will be if you only look at equation $2,3,4$ and take the $x_4$ to the right side.

Comment: @conditionalMethod Thank you, I see it now.